# publically pushed docker images on Amazon ECR is accessible to anyone outside organizations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I am pushing my docker image to aws ecr as public image, can it be pulled by anyone.? Or it can be pulled only within the account users.?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the docs say:

> A private repository does not offer content search capabilities and requires Amazon IAM-based authentication using AWS account credentials before allowing images to be pulled. A public repository has descriptive content and **allows anyone anywhere to pull images without needing an AWS account or using IAM credentials**. Public repository images are also available in the Amazon ECR public gallery.

So, the short answer is *yes, it can be pulled by anyone*.

Comment: can they search ?

Comment: Uhm, yeah, they can.

Comment: can we try this one ? please create one dummy registry in your aws account, let me try viewing in my aws account .

Comment: You don't need an AWS account to view public ECRs.

Comment: And no, I won't create a dummy one.